# filtering the columns during sql runtime

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql query as below

> Select distinct NVL(a.column,'EMPTY') column  from table a  where a.POSTCODE ='MNOP')

possible values of column are X,Y and Z.

I would like to modify the query in such a way that if the query returns more than one value as below

> Ex : X,Y or X,Z or Y,Z or X,Y,Z

Then I would like to return only one value as below

> for X,Y -> I need to return X 
>   for Y,Z -> I need to return Y
>   for X,Z -> I need to return X
>
> (The priority is from X to Z, in the same order)

I am trying to use `count(*)` and some other combinations in the sub query and was not successful so far. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rownum pseudo column to get first row of the result set. And ordering in ascending by the column, you'll a

```
select * from mytable 
where rownum=1
order by mycol ;
```

In your case, try this to retrieve the desired column

```
Select distinct NVL(a.column,'EMPTY') column 
from table a 
where a.POSTCODE ='MNOP'
and rownum=1
order by a.column
```

PS:- "column" is an invalid identifier to be a column name